# AWS Amplify CLI commands give no return value at all unless run with sudo

Tags: aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli

After installing amplify with npm, any amplify command simply returns with no result. No error, no value. If run with sudo, I get a result.

After contacting AWS, I got the answer, so sharing it with anyone else who hits this below:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me, this was due to permissions on the amplify directory. To fix it:

`sudo npm uninstall -g @aws-amplify/cli`

`sudo rm -rf ~/.amplify/`

`npm i -g @aws-amplify/cli`

I believe this removes the configs, so you may need to set up amplify again.

Comment: Yes, it's a permissions / ownership issue. To avoid having to set up the configs, you can `chown username files` or if necessary `sudo chown username files`, where `files` are those owned by root in the .amplify tree.